# using the same field within a subquery of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-insert

how can i make something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO age.page(domain,title_count,youtube_count,ipaddress,updated)
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT domain,
    COUNT(domain) AS titlecount,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE title = table1.title) AS YoutubeCount, ipaddress
    NOW() AS timeNow
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY domain
    ORDER BY title DESC
) a;
```

I want to use a subquery to get a count of a different table but use the same field from the main query.

the reason i want to do this is so i dont have to run two queries instead its only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this `COUNT` in a subquery and then `JOIN` it with the first table:

```
INSERT INTO age.page(domain, title_count, youtube_count, ipaddress, updated)
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      domain,
      COUNT(domain) AS titlecount,
      t2.titlecount AS YoutubeCount, 
      ipaddress,
      NOW() AS timeNow
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT title, COUNT(*) Titlecount
       FROM table2 
       GROUP BY title
    ) AS t2 ON t2.title = table1.title   
    GROUP BY domain
    ORDER BY table1.title DESC
) a;
```

Comment: I get this `Error Code: 1052. Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @Dev-Ria Resolve it using an alias try `table1.title` or `t2.title` instead see my edit.